Difference between dichotomous and ordinal variable for inputation purposes
I'm reading the documentation of the Amelia R package.
In the Ordinal section of the documentation there is written that ordinal variables include dichotomous variables, and one example is gender, which should be treated as an ordinal variable, and if 0 is male and 1 is female, an inputed value of 0.79 is perfectly acceptable.
But the in the nominal section it says that another variable called signed, which is 1 if a country signed an IMF agreement in that year and 0 if it did not, should be treated as a nomial variable, and only 0 and 1 values are acceptable. Floating point variables are not acceptable.
Why gender can be regarded as ordinal while signed can not?
What's wrong with an inputed value of 0.79 for signed, meaning the country would have a 79% probability to sign the agreement?
Related: Can we treat gender as ordinal variable?
